# Entity Framework Partial Entity Update

Tags: entity-framework-5

I am using Asp.net Webapi and EF and i am having issues with partial updates with the Entity Framework 5 .

I usually get say 20 fields from REST services that i need to update out of the complete entity.When I update I set the entity state to Modified.
The whole entity is updated all the time overriding all the existing values in the table that should not be changed as a result of the update.

There are random fields that I got from REST services not fixed fields that can help me to identify what properties are updated.

I want to know how this issue is being resolved out there and what are the practices are used to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on this sentence: _There are random fields that I got from REST services not fixed fields that can help me to identify what properties are updated._

Comment: For example . I have an entity that has 100 fields in database. My services are called by different consumers at a time. They never pass all the 100 fields and I don't know which fields are being passed out of 100. They could be 10 , 20 or 50 fields.. So when I try to update an entity it over rides the fields which were not supposed to be updated along with those fields that I have to update. I hope I clear myself here.

Comment: And the other values are `null`s?

Comment: Sometimes they are null and sometimes they are not. But even if they left a field blank intentionally just to clear it out. I only want to update those fields that are passed in not the entire record.

Comment: @Tabish -- So I am curious what solution did you end up using to handle this problem?

Comment: @Breadtruck .. I analysed and came up with basically couple of options for me . There was nothing i did on EF part. I ended up providing compact object  or you can say partial objects to my consuming clients. That helped to a great extent in saving my effort of over riding fields. For Example Consumer requires a certain set of fields all the time with other fields. So i was providing them exact objects rather then additional fields . (I should have done that earlier). Other option was to allow your consuming client to provide you the list of fields (Kind of metadata) which were changed.